# How to output mysql multiline data in the same format with PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I just started learning how to make a website. I'm making a comment box which is used to enter blog entries. Let's say I types in an entry with 3 lines, and it will show up the same format in mySQL table. But when i try to output it, it becomes one line.

```
//Here's what i did to output the data.
$entry = $row['entry'];
echo "<p>". $entry ."</p>";

//INPUT
Hello,
TEST LINE2
TEST LINE3

//OUTPUT
Hello, TEST LINE2 TEST LINE3
```

Comment: If you start lerning try to use mysqli in youre web-sites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

> "Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string"

```
$entry = $row['entry'];
echo "<p>". nl2br($entry) ."</p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a [`pre`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre) tag, this will prevent white spaces from breaking.

```
$entry = $row['entry'];
echo "<p><pre>". $entry ."</pre></p>";
```

Comment: @ylhtravis what css are you using?

Comment: You can style the <pre> tag with CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$entry = $row['entry'];
echo $entry ."<br />";
```

Or

```
$entry = $row['entry'];
echo $entry ."<br>";
```